# Why would I give away a (tiny) part of my reputation to downvote a post that is clearly spam, instead of just flagging it like so?

Tags: discussion

I just "reviewed" a new user question that was obviously spam, so I flagged it as such during the review. That's one of the reasons why the new uers review process is in place, right?

But the question already had a score of -6 (so at least 6 downvotes). That implies there were 6 people willing to give away 1 point of their reputation. I'd hope they also flagged the question as spam, which I believe is a much more powerful feature.

My (related) questions:

1. even if you only "loose" like 1 point to downvote, and assuming that you're not on any SE site for "just the reputation" (that would be sad), why would you even give 1 such point of yours to that annoying spam question?
2. after such question gets deleted, do the downvoters get there -1 reputation corrected again (ie: does the delete cause something like an undo of the -1)?

Comment: Don't have much time to answer, but don't downvote spam.  Just flag it wiht the spam flag.  Downvoting can actually cause spam to be removed slower.

Comment: @MPD if downvoting slows spam removal, why flagging as spam causes automatic downvote?!

Answer (score 4):

1. Flagging something as spam automatically gives it a downvote (from the [community user](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community), so *you* don't lose any rep.). The -6 rep. score you see is probably 6 spam flags, not manual downvotes.  You may give it an additional manual downvote, but doing so is pointless - just flag it as spam.
2. Yes, if you do a manual downvote, you get your -1 rep. back after it has been deleted.  But don't waste your time downvoting spam - it is the flags that kill it.

The [community user](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) is also in charge of [removing old abandoned questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).

Comment: Interesting answers, thank you for it! hadn't thought of the "time" wasting part of it yet. Any suggestions (like some links added to your answer) about where in the help docu I can read more about this (if any exist)? And also where I can find more docu about all such things (tasks, duties, etc) that that "community user" is supposed to take care of? Note: would be nice if something equivalent to the Drupal "rules" module could step in to block the downvote button after it was flagged X (like 3 ?) times as spam. Have to remember that for my new "ArrayShift" project I started yesterday ...

Comment: As for tasks, duties, etc. for the community user, see its user profile: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community

Comment: Interesting link, hadn't thought of looking like so. It also includes another interesting link, ie http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006 ... would you mind adding those 2 links to your actual answer? I cannot "suggest an edit" to a meta answer .. I learned yesterday .... grrrrrrr

Answer (score -1):

This is what I think the answer is to bullet 1 in my question: Do NOT waste even 1 point to downvoting a spam question or answers. Instead just flag it as spam.

Flagging it as spam is way more effective to get rid of it, and you don't "support" the spammer who's trying to reduce a very little bit the reputation of each of the downvoters.

I'm not sure (yet) what the answer to bullet 2 in my question is ... and I'm not willing to "pay" 1 point for testing it out "in production" (by using a downvote next time I see a spam question in the review process). I'd rather try to find the answer in the help pages ... and then edit my answer here ... some day ...